# Should I use Session authentication when configuring the login screen through drf?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('dj_rest_auth.urls'), name='dj_rest_auth'),
    path('registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls'), name='registration'),
]
```

managers.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    #일반 유저 생성
    def create_user(self, email, password, gender, date_of_birth, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        if not gender:
            raise ValueError(_('The gender must be set'))
        if not date_of_birth:
            raise ValueError(_('The date_of_birth must be set'))
        
        #email 형태를 동일하게 만들기 위한 함수
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            gender=gender,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            **extra_fields)
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    
    #관리자 유저 생성
    def create_superuser(self, email, password,**extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('gender', 2)
        default_date = date(2000,1,1)
        extra_fields.setdefault('date_of_birth', default_date)
        
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication'
    ),
```

when i run the server after writing the code like this

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
[21/Jun/2023 13:25:05] "GET /userapp/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 100395

how can i fix this

I want to use only JWTCookieAuthentication.
Is it possible?